# In Plone, inlined content does not update on document when published

Tags: inline, plone

I have documents in my Plone CMS with content inlined from other objects. Once the document is published to my site the date and time it was last published (ie. last updated) is displayed at the bottom of the page template.

The problem I'm having is that When I re-publish the object from which content is inlined, the changes made to the content displays fine on the document, but the last updated date and time stays the same.

Obviously re-publishing the document itself will update last updated, but i'm wondering why last updated does not update itself automatically when the other object (where content is inlined from) is re-published.

The documents also link to other objects, when these other objects are altered and re-published, the date and time automatically update, without having to re-publish the actual document.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you 'inline' other content? This is not a standard feature of Plone, as far as I can tell from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last modification date is based on the object itself.  Plone cannot automatically detect that you inline some other object's content.

If you "inline" the other objects's content with a simple iframe or so, you're out of luck.

If you wrote your own content type that grabs some other objects's content programmatically: yes, you can fix it.  You'll have to register an event handler that listens to the other object's modification event.

Alternatively, you could write a script that goes through all your content-that-could-have-an-inline, find the content it inlines and updates the modification date if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've written a script that takes the Modification date from the object and compares it to the document, then the doc displays the updated. Thanks for your time